# Google maps gives current position arrow but doesn't load the map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I dropped the maps from iOS and switched to google maps. Now it shows my position but it doesn't load the map. It is gray / yellow with in the bottom left Google.

This is my implementation:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface GoogleMapViewController ()

    @property  (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;


@end

@implementation GoogleMapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    _mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = _mapView;

    [self initLocationManager];

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = _mapView;
}

- (void) initLocationManager
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;
    self.locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation ;
    [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:10.0f] ;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"New locations");
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    _mapView.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:newLocation.coordinate
                                                     zoom:6];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

This is basically the tutorial demo app from Google Dev page, and I'm not sure why it's not loading the map.

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That I just copy pasted the tutorial from the google dev page for the ios sdk. So I don't get it why it doesn't work. It just doesn't show any map.

Comment: Ok. I edited your post. Always make sure to be as clear as possible when you're posting a question. (: Also, have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes I don't get it. I added a screenshot off what I get. Is it because the tutorial uses a CGRECTZERO? I changed the CGRECTZEROT to bounds from the main frame. And then I get that.

Comment: I debugged. It only shows the location where you initialized the camera on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. You need to set the initial camera zoom level on 1 and then zoom in on your current location. That way you can still zoom out and have the whole map available.

If you take a zoomlevel 14 as initial, google maps doesn't load the rest of the map I think.